# Why can I access the /tags connection on a Graph API photo object, but the photo_tag FQL table for the same photo returns nothing?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, facebook-fql

I can access the tags associated with a particular photo via the Graph API, but if I try to query the photo_tag FQL table I get an empty response.  I'm using the same access token in each case (testing this in the Graph API Explorer).

For example, if the `pid` is `123`, then https://graph.facebook.com/123/tags shows me the tags that I want to see, but `select text from photo_tag where pid = '123'` returns nothing.

Is this a bug or did something recently change with Facebook Platform and I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id `123` is probably an `object_id` instead of a `pid`.

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT text FROM photo_tag WHERE object_id = 123
```